# Escape outer variable trap in two nested foreach with Dictionary<T>

Tags: variables, dictionary, foreach, nested, outer-join

I have two objects that I initialize like this:

```
var series = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,int>>()
{
   {"0", new Dictionary<string, int>() },
   {"1", new Dictionary<string, int>() },
   {"2", new Dictionary<string, int>() }
}

var periodValues = new Dictionary<string,int>();
{
   {"Jan", 0 },
   {"Feb", 0 },
   {"Mar", 0 }
}
```

Then I have another object with filled values:

```
 var target = new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,int>>()
 {
       { "0", 
         new Dictionary<string, int>()
         {
            {"Jan", 12 },
            {"Mar", 22 }
         } 
       },
       { "1", 
         new Dictionary<string, int>()
         {
            {"Mar", 37 }
         } 
       },
       { "2", 
         new Dictionary<string, int>()
         {
            {"Jan", 4 },
            {"Feb", 48 },
            {"Mar", 22 }
         } 
       }
 }
```

`series` and `target` have always the same `Key`, while `target[key].Keys` (with `key` of type `string`) for any `key` can be a **subset** (at the most the same) of `periodValues.Keys`.

Now I want to fill `series.Values` according to the keys in `periodValues.Keys` but with the values of `target[key].Value`. Therefore:

```
foreach (var numberValue in target.Keys)
{
    foreach (var period in target[numberValue].Keys)
    {
        periodValues[period] = target[numberValue][period];
    }
    series[numberValue] = periodValues;
}
```

But I fall in the **outer variable trap**...that means all `series[key]` for any `series.Keys` are equal to the last `periodValues`. I tried many solutions to escape the outer variable trap according to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx) with no luck. Anybody knows a solution or maybe a better approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anybody interested, I solved the problem by declaring and initializing `periodValues` inside the first `foreach`:

```
foreach (var numberValue in target.Keys)
{
    var periodValues = new Dictionary<string,int>();
    {
       {"Jan", 0 },
       {"Feb", 0 },
       {"Mar", 0 }
    }
    foreach (var period in target[numberValue].Keys)
    {
        periodValues[period] = target[numberValue][period];
    }
    series[numberValue] = periodValues;
}
```